gtk library in visual studio 2019
enter image description here
Hello, who can help me to solve problem with define gtk on visual studio. I have problem with the linker.
I try to create window with gtk. But I have a problem with the linker. Here the problem from visual studio(2019):
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'gtk-3.lib'    Gif_maker   C:\Users\Cyber_User\source\repos\Gif_maker\Gif_maker\LINK   1"


A similar question has been asked here before, you should check it out link
